# Never ending loop on element availability / visibility

Tags: selenium, c#, appium, .net

I have written below code to make test script wait till some of my elements get loaded.
But what if, that element will never get loaded? That means if `TopWorkOrderCard.Displayed` will never get displayed, then my loop will be a never ending loop.

How to handle situations like this?

sample code:

```
public void WaitforWOlist(int WaitTime)
        {
            try
            {

                    if (TopWorkOrderCard.Displayed == true)
                    {
                        //do nothing
                    }


            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(WaitTime);

                WaitforWOlist(2000);


            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
 public void WaitforWOlist(int WaitTime, int counter)
   {
    if (counter > 20)
    {
        return;
    }
    try
    {
        if (TopWorkOrderCard.Displayed == true)
        {
            //do nothing
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(WaitTime);
        WaitforWOlist(2000, counter + 1);

    }
```

Comment: This seems OK. we can set the counter ...Thanks